# Modify all queries in Zend\Db (add where)

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-table

I need to modify all queries that are executed through `Zend\Db` before sending them to DB.

Basically it needs to add additional `WHERE` statement to all selects, updates and deletes and additional column and value in inserts.

I was thinking about writing my own `TableGateway` feature for that, the problem is that I would like to avoid being restricted to `TableGateway` alone and have this functionality while using `Zend\Db\Adapter` and `TableGateway` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up writing custom db adapter that handles all the logic. I'll probably share it as an open source if I'll have a time to clean up the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at some of the events dispatched from the table gateway if that make sense in your context: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.4/namespaces/Zend.Db.TableGateway.Feature.EventFeature.html

There is a preSelect event that is triggered and which you can probably listen to.

Comment: thanks Thomas, the problem is that all `Features` are for `TableGateway` only, I need to have such flexibility of altering queries on an adapter level.